# FileProvider with external folder

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to open a file (using the FileProvider) that is stored in a private folder

```
File appFiles = new File(externalPath.getAbsolutePath() +
    "/Android/data/com.my.nice.domain/files/Container/");
```

Then inside the `appFiles` i'm creating subfolder and store files inside the sub folder

my *files_path.xml* looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_path4" 
        path="Android/data/com.my.nice.domain/files/Container/"/>
</paths>
```

Relevant manifest xml code snippet

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="com.my.nice.domain.fileprovider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

and this is how I'm using the FileProvider to open the files (to view them with the default viewer)

```
File f = new File(url);
String AUTHORITY="com.my.nice.domain.fileprovider";
Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), AUTHORITY, f);
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(i);
```

but for some reason its not working, and I'm getting error saying that file not found

example for error message that I'm getting

**File not found (content://com.my.nice.domain.fileprovider/my_path4/576feb25/535d8216.xlsx**)

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you given  permission in manifest?

Comment: @AmruthaSaj yes , `android:grantUriPermissions="true"` (its written in the question)

Comment: try to check if `file.exists()`, maybe there is no such file at all?